# sharpkml invalid portable project type

Tags: express, types, project, portability, sharpkml

Between the Google Earth API being deprecated in less than a month and the power of KML/Z files underpinning Google Earth and Bing Maps, I am keenly interested in SharpKML.  I hope to use it to geographically 20+ Kodachrome-digitized-scanned slideshows!

Thus I downloaded and unzipped sharpkml-44444.zip fromhttps://sharpkml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest, which yielded a SharpKML.sln and 5 projects.  Using Visual Studio 15 Express for Windows, I opened SharpKML.sln.  Among the 5 projects, 4 opened and 1 did not:

Unsupported 
     - SharpKml.Core, "C:\Users\Preferred customer\SharpKml Website ZipSources\SharpKml\SharpKml.Core.csproj"

These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - Examples, "C:\Users\Preferred customer\SharpKml Website ZipSources\Examples\Examples.csproj"
     - UnitTests, "C:\Users\Preferred customer\SharpKml Website ZipSources\UnitTests\UnitTests.csproj"
     - SharpKml.Kmz, "C:\Users\Preferred customer\SharpKml Website ZipSources\SharpKml.Kmz\SharpKml.Kmz.csproj"
     - SharpKml, "C:\Users\Preferred customer\SharpKml Website ZipSources\SharpKml.sln"

The most important SharpKml.Core.csproj could not open!  From SharpKML's original VS 13, its Portable Class Library ProjectType --- ProjectGuid 786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB --- is no longer supported under Studio 15!  At the http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2012/05/portable-class-library-projects-and.html page, I tried downloading and running PortableLibraryTools.exe /buildmachine, but that did NOT work either.  It was a 2010 posting; was it too obsolete?

For me, this is a landmark frustration. KML is state of the art; SharpKML is beautifully engineered!  But, [expletive] it dies because of a Studio Version 13 to 15 incompatibility.  C'mon, guys!

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: The question.  Can the whole VS 2013 solution be made to build under VS Express 2015?  Or, is it ruined by one 2015-broken Class Library ProjectType?   Without resorting to VS 2013, is SharpKML permanently broken?